# Telegram Bot API errors codes (integrating Groups and Channels)

Tags: api, chat, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm working on my open-source project [BOTServer](https://github.com/solyaris/BOTServer) a http://telegram.org Bot Platform Webhooks Server, for Rubyists.

I experienced strange error when sending messages (`sendMessage` API endpoint) on a Telegram Bot I created. when sending messages to a specific Bot I created, I got these errors:

1. Error code 400 -> **Bad Request: group is deactivated**

   `Telegram::Bot::Exceptions::ResponseError - Telegram API has returned the error. (ok: "false", error_code: "400", description: "[Error]: Bad Request: group is deactivated")`

and/or

2. Error code 403 -> **Bot was kicked from a chat**

   `Telegram::Bot::Exceptions::ResponseError - Telegram API has returned the error. (ok: "false", error_code: "403", description: "[Error]: Bot was kicked from a chat")`

That's really strange.
It seems that the problem is related to the "story" of a specific Bot (errors are not systematic and I do not have issues with another bot). In facts I done these steps:

1. I create the bot (lets cal it: MYbot)
2. I ADDED the bot to a Telegram Group (e.g. MYGroup)
3. I REMOVED the bot from the Group
4. I send messages from the bot in reply to a user (then I got errors)

**Question 1**
Ok I'm pretty sure something wrong happened Telegram Serve side and I could delete and rebuild the bot... Any better idea about a solution ?

**Question 2**
There is a published list of Telegram Bot errors ? I didn't find in Telegram Bot documentation/tutorials.

I love Telegram architecture! But I feel there are some issue/bugs with Bots APIs especially in recent possibilities to insert Bots in Groups and Cahnnel. Any similar experience ?

Comment: Dont understand 4). Are you sure that you send message to user after he start communicating with your bot?

Comment: yes, I'm sure; I'ts a bot reply. 
BTW, IMMO Bot can start a unsolicited conversation with a user (having his chat ID, that's permanent)

Comment: AFAIK, bot can't start conversation even with explicit chat_id. User should write first. I never had such problems, so maybe you send message to wrong id (to group for example). I know it's not a great solution, but you could check twice :) i don't think it's telegram server problem

Comment: Yes and not: a Bot CAN send unsolicited message to chat ID of a user (CURRENTLY subscribed to the bot, of course). But in my case, as I said, the bot reply to a user queuest (bot receive an update and reply)

Comment: Does it happens regardless the message you send? I mean, is it solved if you send a different message? Can you also post an example of your request?

Comment: @RubenBermudez yes, see my answer here below.

Comment: I still have the issue now "Something went wrong, please try again."

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself having found a possible reason of the problem. The problem arise just with a single specific Bot I created in past (and I removed from a group). As specificed in question:

## Step by step story

- step 1:
  After creation I added that bot on a **group** with 2 users: (myself and a second person).
- step 2:
  Afterward I removed that bot from the group.
- step 3:
  I used that bot to test my [BOTserver](https://github.com/solyaris/BOTServer)
  sending SendMessage od reply to webhook update.
  Now i experienced the mentioned 400/403 errors.
- step 4:
  I **DELETED** that Bot, chatting with BotFather.
- step 5:
  I created again the same Bot with the **SAME identichal name*
- Step 6:
  I tested again, an I rised the usual issue:

  `Telegram API has returned the error. (ok: "false", error_code: "401", description: "[Error]: Unauthorized"):`
- Step 7:
  I created new bot(s) with **different name(s)**
  Finally, no more errors!

## Conclusion:

I fair **the original Bot name remained in a "wrong" Telegram server internal status.** My hypotesis is that adding/removing Bots from Groups have some problem/bug.

## My Solution:

- delete the bot name created problems, no more using that "name" :(
- recreate a bot with different name.

Any similar experience ?

Comment: I had similar experience with broadcast channels. I created one long time ago and left untouched for a while. When, recently, people try to suscribe into the channel a error rise. Then I delete the channel, create it again and everything goes right. I even notice that UI channel has changed! Maybe the problem is a mix of "wrong" Telegram server internal status and the telegram client app version.

Comment: @jlvaquero yes... the scenario I described, happened before major client app updates (months ago), so my hypoteis is about some "wrong" internal status error for some "old" bot names.

Answer (score 0):

I,m getting this error through `WebHook` requests.
This issue occurs after adding bot to a group and disable bot `Add to group` feature via `BotFather`.

This issue exists until i fetch updates manually by `/getUpdates` method and make them passed for Telegram server and after that `WebHook` works fine.

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: @Masoud thanxs, but is not fully clear your experience. My  you want to explain step by step sequence ?

Answer (score 0):

return ok if bot API return respond error, like this example

```
try {
        return Telegram::sendMessage($message);
    } catch (TelegramResponseException $exception) {
        Log::info($exception->getMessage());
        return ['ok' => 'true'];
    }
```